# How to get files in order of date in R?

Tags: r, file, sorting

I'm trying to get the files but I need to get them in date order.

For example:

```
x <- c("A_2020.07.01.xls", "A_2020.07.02.xls", "A_2020.06.29.xls", "A_2020.06.30.xls")
```

*Necessarily listed as above.

The code I use is as follows:

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls") #pattern
df_list <- lapply(file_list, read_excel) #list
df <- ldply(df_list, data.frame) #dataframe
```

What should I do to get them as I want?

```
A_2020.06.29.xls
A_2020.06.30.xls
A_2020.07.01.xls
A_2020.07.02.xls
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `sort(file_list)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ordering your files inside a dataframe, and then using them for the data loading process:

```
#Data
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls") 
df <- data.frame(file_list,stringsAsFactors = F)
df$Date <- gsub("[^\\d]+", "", df$file_list, perl=TRUE)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,'%Y%m%d')
#Order
df <- df[order(df$Date),]
#Create new input for read
vecread <- df$file_list
#Read files
df_list <- lapply(vecread, read_excel) #list
df <- ldply(df_list, data.frame) #dataframe
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks @Duck

Answer (score 2):

Given this vector

```
x <- c("A_2020.07.01.xls", "A_2020.07.02.xls", "A_2020.06.29.xls", "A_2020.06.30.xls")
```

you can convert it to date class, order it and sort `x` based on that order:

```
x[order(as.Date(x, format = "A_%Y.%m.%d.xls"))]
# [1] "A_2020.06.29.xls" "A_2020.06.30.xls" "A_2020.07.01.xls" "A_2020.07.02.xls"
```